# gob decoder attempting to decode into a non-pointer

Tags: go, gob

In my Go program I am encoding []byte data with gob

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(buf)
        //data is []byte
        buf.Reset()
        enc.Encode(data)
```

but getting '*gob decoder attempting to decode into a non-pointer*' when I am trying to decoded

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    d := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
        d.Decode(data)
        log.Printf("%s", d)
```

Comment: It says `data` isn't a pointer. Have you tried using a pointer?

Comment: I think this is just a typo, should be data instead d in log print..;(

Answer (score 2):

Gob requires you to pass a pointer to decode.

In your case, you would do:

```
    d.Decode(&data)
```

reason being, it may have to modify the slice (ie: to make it bigger, to fit the decoded array)